# How to set id dynamically in URL using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I need one help.I need to set the id dynamically in URL within anchor tag using PHP.I am adding my code below.

```
$message='<p>You recently requested to reset your password.You can reset password by following the link below.If you no longer need to rest your password ,you can ignore this message.</p></br><p><a href="http://localhost/spesh/#/resetPass?">Click here</a></p>';
```

The above content will go the user's email id.When user will click on `click here` link the url should open.Here i need to set `id=2` after `?`.Please help me.

Comment: your url _http://localhost/spesh/#/resetPass?id=2_ will not be able to get id

Comment: Do you think after hash `#` you can pass query string and get it in php?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 No, but you can get it in JavaScript, which is what I'm guessing he's doing.

Comment: @subhra wher you will use this id (in PHP or JS)?

Answer (score 0):

Handle your url without hashtag `#` , If you are not using any type of angular  routing, to get

```
$var = 2;
$message = "<a href='http://localhost/spesh/resetPass/?id=$var'>Click here</a>";
```

**Warning** :

If Anybody know your website they can try to reset all password by using any Id's, so be care about this and use token in your each reset request. like this

```
 http://localhost/spesh/resetPass/?id=$var&token=23l4klkffgdkoiowlkfwokew
```

Comment: is this set id dynamically? i think not.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that you're getting the ID from the database somewhere, or from a session. In that the case, get the ID *somehow* into a variable (let's call it `$userId`), escape it for HTML (to prevent **[Cross-Site Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)** (which is a fancy name for HTML injection)), and add it to your `href` attribute:

```
$userId = htmlspecialchars(somehowGetUserId());
$message="<p>You recently requested to reset your password.You can reset password by following the link below.If you no longer need to rest your password ,you can ignore this message.</p></br><p><a href="http://localhost/spesh/#/resetPass?id=$userId">Click here</a></p>";
```

Where `somehowGetUserId()` is a function I leave you to implement however you like. The idea is that it returns the user ID "somehow".

Note how I also replaced your single quotes with double quotes, to allow for easy interpolation of the variable inside.

Note that this won't work for server-side `$_GET`, since the browser will not send anything to the server after the `#`, if want PHP to see the `id=2`, you'll need to move `?id=$userId` to before the `#` in the URL.

Answer (score -1):

If your id is in a variable called $id, then:

```
$message='<p>You recently requested to reset your password.You can reset password by following the link below.If you no longer need to rest your password ,you can ignore this message.</p></br><p><a href="http://localhost/spesh/#/resetPass?id={$id}">Click here</a></p>';
```

Comment: Do you think after hash `#` you can pass query string and get it in php?

Comment: How so? I make no assumptions about the id variable being externally set - most likely it would come from an internally checked source. @MadaraUchiha

Comment: please give your answer.  @itzmukeshy7

Comment: @davedavedave I make no assumptions about the ID variable being internally set or checked. It doesn't cost a lot to escape anything coming out of your app, and it's really helpful in preventing things when you do need to prevent them.